# DB2 two instances same database name

Tags: db2

I have 2 DB2 instances in one machine, instances DB2 and DB2_01.

DB2 was the first instance I've installed, DB2_01 was the last installed and is the default instance. When I use db2.exe in the instance DB2_01 with CREATE DATABASE XXX, the db2.exe try to create XXX in the instance DB2 and not in DB2_01.

What can I do to direct my comands to the right instance (DB2_01) using db2.exe ?

Can I have one database called  XXX in instance DB2 and other database with the same name XXX in the other instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly attach to the instance first before issuing your command.

i.e. 
db2 attach to DB2_01
db2 create db XXX

And yes you can have the same database name in different instances. Each instance is a separate database management environment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm used to do db2cmd then db2. Is this alright ? When I try attach to <instance1> it works, then, in the same prompt, I do attach to <instance2> it fails with message: SQL1027N  The node directory cannot be found.

Comment: I feel like it have 1 node directory for 2 installations (port 50000 and 50001) because I still can't create database with same name to 2 different instances. This is really weird ... I must be wrong.

Comment: You should detach from the previous instance before attaching to the new instance. Then try creating your database with same name.